# How does input from insertUI get stored?

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a SelectizeInput() UI using the insertUI() function. Essentially, I have an action button which adds a SelectizeInput() every time it's clicked. The idea is that the user selects columns from their data to put into groups. The creation of the UI works fine. I can also see in the Shiny trace that the selection works fine. However, I'm unsure how to access these variables to use in later plots. This is the code I have:

UI:

```
actionButton("cr_exp", "Create new biological group")
```

Server:

```
  observeEvent(input$cr_exp, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#cr_exp",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp), label = "Select samples", choices = colnames(exp_dff()), options = list(create=TRUE), multiple=TRUE))
      tags$div(id = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp))
  })
```

In the shiny trace, it shows that the group is created, but I can't figure out how to access the value:

```
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"grp1":["MV4negControl01","MV4negControl02"]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You access the values just like any other input values: by the input element’s
id from the `input` reactive values:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("cr_exp", "Create new biological group"),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$cr_exp, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#cr_exp",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = selectizeInput(
        inputId = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp),
        label = "Select samples",
        choices = LETTERS,
        options = list(create = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
    tags$div(id = paste0("grp", input$cr_exp))
  })
  
  output$choices <- renderPrint({
    lapply(seq_len(input$cr_exp), function(i) input[[paste0("grp", i)]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```